# When I download the Excel File from the website I am unable to see it's contents

Tags: asp.net, excel, vb.net, gridview

I have a website in Asp.net wherein I have implemented a button to Store GridView in an Excel Format but when I open the file I am unable to see the actual contents of the GridView and I can only see the column headings. I have used three following imports after installing EPPlus via NuGet Package Manager.

```
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System.IO;
using WebFormsTest.Models;
```

My code behind is as follows

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim GetProducts As Object = Nothing
        GridView6.DataSource = GetProducts
        GridView6.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Response.Clear()
    Dim products = GetProducts()
    GridView6.DataSource = products
    GridView6.DataBind()
    Dim excel As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage
    Dim workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Products")
    Dim totalCols = GridView6.Rows(0).Cells.Count
    Dim totalRows = GridView6.Rows.Count
    Dim headerRow = GridView6.HeaderRow
    worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(GetProducts())
    Dim memoryStream = New MemoryStream
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=products.xlsx")
    excel.SaveAs(memoryStream)
    memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub



Public Function GetProducts() As List(Of Product)

End Function
```

My Aspx button is as given below

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="EXPORT RTD TO EXCEL" onclick="Button3_Click" BackColor="#FF9966"  CssClass="btn btn-large" Font-Bold="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the code behind to the following solves this problem and via the Nuget Package Manager we can download ClosedXML so that it includes the following import

```
Imports ClosedXML.Excel


Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable("GridView_Data")
    For Each cell As TableCell In GridView5.HeaderRow.Cells
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text)
    Next
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView5.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add()
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = row.Cells(i).Text
        Next
    Next
    Dim wb As New XLWorkbook
    wb.Worksheets.Add(dt)
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewPOLQA.xlsx")
    Using MyMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream)
        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.[End]()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the datatype is of `products`, but why not bind it directly to the sheet?

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(GetProducts());
```

And you are not seeing the contents of the GridView on `Button3_Click` because you are sending an Excel file to the client (by setting the `Response.ContentType`), not an updated html page where the GridView has been filled with `products`.

Quick demo translated from C# to vb

```
Dim excelPackage As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage
Dim worksheet As ExcelWorksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1")

worksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromCollection(GetProducts())

Dim bin() As Byte = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray

Response.ClearHeaders
Response.Clear
Response.Buffer = true
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString)
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""mySheet.xlsx"""")", Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length))
Response.Flush
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest
```

Comment: When I replaced the `workSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = headerRow.Cells((i - 1)).Text` with
`worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(products)` It is giving me the message Property Access must assign to the property or use its value.

Comment: Are you still using loops? because that one row in my example should be sufficient. See https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8223/filling-the-document-with-data/26425/fill-from-collection#t=201707261918225613912

Comment: I removed the loops still shooting the error Property Access must assign to the property or use its value

Comment: Remove all the code and start over like the link in my comment. Try if you get an excel sheet with `books`. If so expand step by step until you get the desired result.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice I'll follow that and update you.

Comment: Updated a quick VB example

Comment: I implemented the VB example it's giving error on line `worksheet.Cells("A1").LoadFromCollection(GetProducts())` Value cannot be null.

Comment: Then your `GetProducts()` method returns `null`. Fix that so it returns the correct data.

Comment: What exactly must I insert into the GetProducts() method so that it does not return null value